# List of IPs and get who owns them

Tags: python, ip

I have a list of IP addresses, is there a way to return who owns those IP addresses? For example, I have two IP addresses on my webpage connecting from a company, how can I get back who owns those IP addresses?

Is it possible? Something like the DNS but the opposite way.

Any libraries on python for this?

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901010/reverse-dns-lookup-in-python) not answer your question? For instance have you not tried `socket.getnameinfo`?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it in loop and provide IP address from list.
`import socket`

```
ip_address_list = ["69.59.196.211","192.168.1.1"]
for i in ip_address_list:
    print(socket.gethostbyaddr(i))
```